# JPA Reverse Engineering multiple Datasources

Tags: jpa

I am using Eclipse, and my application works with two different DBs.
I am able to reverse engineer one DB or the other, but I do not see how to set things up so that I may reverse both DBs. I only see that I may select one datasource.
Is it possible to do this and I just do not see how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make another EJB project and add it to the EAR